# calling an extern (static) function in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to put some c++ functions together. I have a file that contains these two functions:

```
double fun1(double *x, int y, double *z){
....
}
```

and

```
static
double fun2(double a, double b, int c){
...
}
```

now, fun1 calls fun2. I want to use fun1 in a separate file (`separate.cpp`), so I do:

```
extern double fun1(double *x, int y, double *z);
```

at the beginning of that  (`separate.cpp`) file.

- Question: should I also write

  extern double fun2(double a, double b, int c);

at the beginning of `separate.cpp` and If so, how? (should I also include the `static` keyword in there, next to `extern`?)

I think my main problem is that I have never used a `static` function before, so I don't really know how to handle them.

Currently, the code compiles but upon loading I get:

```
unable to load shared object '/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/abc/libs/abc.so':
  /R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/abc/libs/abc.so: undefined symbol: _Z6fun1PdiS_Pi
```

Comment: Doesn't using `static` for a definition made **inside** a translation unit (same as for c), actually hide the definition from being visible for linkage by another TU?

Comment: remove static if that is global function (not a method). such static means local (invisible to other files).

Comment: In this context `static` hides the function from everything outside the current translation unit. So it can only be called by functions in the same translation unit.

Comment: Are you sure about the error message, in particular the mangled name `_Z6fun1PdiS_Pi`? The `c++filt` program can't decipher it.

Comment: @TonyK: fun1 is not the real name of the function....The actual name is longer to type:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to declare the static function in your separate file, because the code there doesn't need to know anything about it. In fact, the purpose of making a function static is to keep it local to the file in which it is defined: it cannot be viewed as extern function in other files.

The error message that you get is about fun1 which is not found.  You have to provide the object file containing fun1 when you compile & link separate.cpp.

Comment: thanks. The file that contains the definition of fun1 is in the same folder so it's enough to just declare the function with the extern keyword --at least that's how I did it for the other functions, not sure why this one isn't working this way.

Comment: `fun1`'s declaration has to be visible to the code that is calling `fun1`